# select2: how to refresh options after dynamically loading ajax content, without reset of search box?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I've read through the documentation of select2, and it doesn't seem to have a way to refresh the options, without closing the select.

Current way of doing it (works, but resets search term):

```
$('#charity-list').select2('close');
$('#charity-list').select2('open');
```

Full code:

```
function fetchCharityListForSearchTerm(searchTerm) {
    console.log('search term ', searchTerm);
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/api/charities/search',
        data: {
            search_term: searchTerm
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        var charitySelect = document.getElementById('charity-list');
        var charities = response.data.data;

        charitySelect.options.length = 0;
        
        charities.forEach((entry) => {
            var newOption = new Option(entry.name, entry.charity_id, false, false);
            $('#charity-list').append(newOption).trigger('change');
        });

        $('#charity-list').select2('close');
        $('#charity-list').select2('open');
    });
}
```

Comment: You should probably use Ajax data fetch option in select2 for this https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Comment: @Ashu I did, and all results resulted in greyed out options which I couldn't select, with no documentation from select2's page on why.

Answer (score 0):

call when came by ajax after success ajax function

```
> $('#charity-list').val(null).trigger('change.select2');
```

Comment: Yeah I did try this, it didn't work. It seems to work if you click out of the textbox then back in, but it doesn't auto refresh the options as they're added to the `<select>` tag.